# I want to redirect domain.com/index.php to domain.com

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How to redirect mydomainname.com/index.php to mydomainname.com

Currently I use following codes also.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mydomianname\.com
    RewriteRule (.*) http://mydomianname.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php\?p=([^\s&]+) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be your complete `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mydomianname\.com
    RewriteRule (.*) http://mydomianname.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php\?p=([^\s&]+) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

    # remove index.php
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

This example only works for http, but should roughly do the trick.

```
# Redirect requests with index.php to the corresponding request
# without the index.php 
RewriteRule ^index.php(.*) http://mydomianname.com$1 [R=301,L]
```